# Counting the previous one visited prior to a specific page in a time-ordered page-view dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have created the following dataframe listing the pages visited by users in an ascending order of the visit date. There are in total 5 pages: BLQ2_1 to BLQ2_5.

```
user_id  created_at  PAGE  
72672    2017-02-20  BLQ2_1
72672    2017-03-03  BLQ2_5
72672    2017-03-03  BLQ2_3
72672    2017-03-05  BLQ2_4
12370    2017-03-06  BLQ2_4
12370    2017-03-06  BLQ2_5
12370    2017-03-06  BLQ2_3
94822    2017-03-06  BLQ2_2
94822    2017-03-10  BLQ2_4
94822    2017-03-10  BLQ2_5
94822    2017-02-24  BLQ2_4
```

For each page I want to obtain statistics about the previous page visited considering all users. That is, I need to calculate the statistic for each page like:

> Path to BLQ2_5 is: 2 times from BLQ2_4 and 1 time from BLQ2_1.
>
> Path to BLQ2_3 is: 2 times from BLQ2_5 and 1 time from BLQ2_4.
>
> Path to BLQ2_4 is: 1 time from BLQ2_5, 1 time from BLQ2_3, 1 time from BLQ2_2, and 1 time from nowhere.

Do I have to use a loop for this? Or is there a way to utilize `groupby` function of pandas? Any suggestions?

Below is my solution using for loop:

```
pg_BLQ2_5 = pd.DataFrame()
pg_BLQ2_4 = pd.DataFrame()
pg_BLQ2_3 = pd.DataFrame()
pg_BLQ2_2 = pd.DataFrame()
pg_BLQ2_1 = pd.DataFrame()
first_pages = pd.DataFrame()

for user_id in df['user_id'].unique():
    #get only current user's records, and reset index
    _pg = df[df['user_id'] == user_id].reset_index()
    _pg.drop('index', axis=1, inplace=True)
    
    #if this is the first page visited, treat differently
    first_page = _pg.iloc[0]
    first_pages = first_pages.append(first_page)

    #exclude the first page visited from the dataframe
    _pg = _pg.loc[1:].reset_index()
    _pg.drop('index', axis=1, inplace=True)

    #for each page, get the record from its previous index, and build the dataframe.
    pg_BLQ2_5 = pg_BLQ2_5.append(_pg.iloc[_pg[_pg['PAGE'] == 'BLQ2_5'].index -1])
    pg_BLQ2_4 = pg_BLQ2_4.append(_pg.iloc[_pg[_pg['PAGE'] == 'BLQ2_4'].index -1])
    pg_BLQ2_3 = pg_BLQ2_3.append(_pg.iloc[_pg[_pg['PAGE'] == 'BLQ2_3'].index -1])
    pg_BLQ2_2 = pg_BLQ2_2.append(_pg.iloc[_pg[_pg['PAGE'] == 'BLQ2_2'].index -1])
    pg_BLQ2_1 = pg_BLQ2_1.append(_pg.iloc[_pg[_pg['PAGE'] == 'BLQ2_1'].index -1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a column that shows the previous page (this assumes the dataframe is sorted by user then by date):

```
df['prev'] = df['PAGE'].shift()
# remove when different user
df['prev'] = df['prev'].where(df['user_id'].shift() == df['user_id'], np.nan)
```

Then simply `groupby` and count values:

```
df.groupby('PAGE')['prev'].value_counts()

PAGE    prev  
BLQ2_3  BLQ2_5    2
BLQ2_4  BLQ2_2    1
        BLQ2_3    1
        BLQ2_5    1
BLQ2_5  BLQ2_4    2
        BLQ2_1    1
```

You can also reshape with `unstack` for instance.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Above in the OP, I shared my approach using for-loop. However, for some reason the results I get is totally different than the results I get with your solution. I don't see any problems in either solutions but could not figure out the problem. Do you have any idea? With your code: `BLQ2_2 ->  BLQ2_1 = 151` , with my code, it is `68`.

Comment: How about the small example you posted? I was getting different results from what you suggested, but I thought you had not shown the full dataframe. Do you also get different results with this one?

Comment: Yes sir, I am trying to figure out using the sample data I shared. I think my code has a problem.

Comment: I found the problem in your code. You should not remove the first page in `_pg`. Say `BLQ2_4` is the second page (and now first after dropping). Then `index` is `0`, `index-1` is `-1`, and you select... the last page!